# StencilJS E2E testing: How do you dispatch a custom event?

Tags: typescript, web-component, e2e-testing, stenciljs

How do you dispatch a CustomEvent to an element in StencilJS E2E testing:

```
const page = await newE2EPage({html: `<my-component></my-component>`});
let component = await page.find('my-component');

?? component.dispatch(new Event('my-event'));
```

In the code above I'm trying to dispatch a customEvent to my component so I can test to see it responds correctly.  But I do not see any way of doing this in newE2EPage.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stenciljs provides a function triggerEvent on it's [E2EElement class](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/9d55304f82cff5d64d8a1aba8ca86e693ca088fb/src/testing/puppeteer/puppeteer-element.ts#L38).

You can do:

```
const page = await newE2EPage();
await page.setContent('some-markup-with-your-component');
const el = page.find('#element-that-would-emit');
el.triggerEvent('some-custom-event');
await page.waitForChanges();
//Your expect assertion here.
```